# Show jQuery popup only at first visit of a page

Tags: jquery

I am new to [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery), and I have some needs on my website. I want to show the jQuery div popup at the first time only when the user comes. No need to show again and again.

Still I am using this, but I don't know how to hide at the second time:

```
var isshow=0;
$(document).ready(function() {
   if (isshow == 0) {
     $('#jPopup').show();
   }
   isshow = 1;
});
```

But the ishow variable initializes every time.

Comment: You can use cookie or local storage for this.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use localstorage. It is easy to understand and use.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var isshow = localStorage.getItem('isshow');
    if (isshow== null) {
        localStorage.setItem('isshow', 1);

        // Show popup here
        $('#jPopup').show();
    }
});
```

It will show you the popup at first visit of your site.

Comment: Thanks @umesh , its working fine for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Shouldn't the variable name of `getItem` and `setItem` be the same?

Comment: @Bijan, It should be the same.

Comment: @UmeshSehta not necessarily. `isshow` will always be null because you are setting the value of a different variable name.

Answer (score 6):

You may use [SessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)  or [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for this as per your need.

If you need to do only for that session, use SessionStorage. If it should be stored permanently in the user's browser, use LocalStorage.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if(sessionStorage && !sessionStorage.getItem('isshow')){
            $('#jPopup').show();
            sessionStorage.setItem('isshow', true);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for this purpose as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var shown= localStorage.getItem('isshow');
    if(shown !="t"){
        $('#jPopup').show();
        localStorage.setItem('isshow', "t");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set a cookie to store a value and check if it is not set then show popup:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var isshow = $.cookie("isshow");
    if (isshow == null) {
        $.cookie("isshow", 1); // Store

        // Show popup here
        $('#jPopup').show();
    }
});
```

Or you can set `localStorage`. Here is a working example. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2D67/159/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(localStorage.getItem('popState') != 'shown') {
        $("#popup").delay(2000).fadeIn();
        localStorage.setItem('popState','shown')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to hide it on load or do it in css (recommended)and then check localstorage to see if it is the first visit.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#jPopup').hide(); //hide on load or in css, later check if its the first visit
        var isshow= localStorage.getItem('status');
        //check if it is the first visit
        if (isshow == null || isshow == '') {
            //set variable to 1
            localStorage.setItem('isshow', 1);
            $('#jPopup').show();
        }
        });
```

Comment: @Tal Do you have any style guide links which would advise that? Personally I find it at least mildly annoying to see a big popup appear for a split second as the DOM loads before the script gets executed.